# How to Pass & as a http request value

Tags: java, httprequest, httpresponse

This might be very silly question but here it goes.

I want to pass `&` as a http request and get the response but the issue is when ever I try to pass `&` as a value its truncates the value after the and character.

Example :

Request :

```
http://10.240.321.26:8080/lr/so/lotcharges?stage=settlement-complete&slevel=75&lttyp=standard&t=DS&**des=CU%20STD%20W/RUN%20&%20DRIVE%20VER&hp=Y&cd=01/15/2016&a=Y&cod=01/19/2016&c=&sc=$0.00
```

Response :

```
{"fieldname":"Description","value":"**CU STD W/RUN** "}
```

Expected Response :

```
CU STD W/RUN & DRIVE VER
```

Comment: Jumped the gun. It's `%26` for `&`

Comment: Read about URL Encoding.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yeah, changed it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - Thanks. It will be %26 for &.

Comment: @JdM The issue is more general - you have to URL encode each of the values, fully. Not just the `&`. The same issue can occur with `=`, `/` and other "unsafe" characters. Thus, it's important to understand URL encoding.